# Get android.R.attr.listPreferredItemHeightLarge in picasso (Resources$NotFoundException error)

Tags: android, android-resources, picasso

According to the [javadoc](http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#resizeDimen%28int,%20int%29) of Picasso the constructor of `resizeDimen()` is:

```
public RequestCreator resizeDimen(int targetWidthResId,
                              int targetHeightResId)
```

So use a system attribute in my code:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(URL)
    .resizeDimen(android.R.attr.listPreferredItemHeightLarge, 
                 android.R.attr.listPreferredItemHeightLarge)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(holder.Logo);
```

But I get:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(7588): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1010386
```

Which I don't understand since a typical `System.out.println(android.R.attr.listPreferredItemHeightLarge);` will return the id of the object in practice:

```
I/System.out(7588): 16843654
```

Why do I get the error here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to be a `Dimension` resource id (a `<dimen>` resource), not a `Dimension` attribute id.